# VB 6.0 error while accessing web service: 2146697208

Tags: web-services, vb6, windows-server-2003

I am getting error : -2146697208, while sending xml to payment gateway web service. The application is developed in VB6.0 and the OS is Microsoft windows server 2003.

And also the code works fine in Windows XP, and i verified the same with third party tools for testing Web Services (SOAP UI) in Windows Embedded Standard system and it works fine. Looks like the issue is related to VB6.0 and the OS. Please help.

Code Snippet:

```
 On Error GoTo 0
'Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")

 PaymentURL = "https://testpayments.globalone.me/merchant/xmlpayment"

 Dim http As Object

 Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

 http.Open "POST", PaymentURL, False

 http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"

http.send (xmldata) (error is thrown here)
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/3436a2e9-e62c-49a3-86de-272d595fa455/vb-60-error-while-accessing-web-service-2146697208?forum=posready  ?

Comment: Try using `CVar` function like this -- `httpReq.send CVar(vXML)`